# No module name `keras` under tmux on AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, keras, gpu, tmux

I am trying to use Amazon AWS instance to train my network. To run it under keras, I need to run

```
source activate tensorflow_p36
```

first and it works. Unfortunately, if I do the same from under `tmux`, it says it can't find `keras` module.

Why and how to overcome?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645053/how-do-i-start-tmux-with-my-current-environment) might solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the solution suggested in [TMUX Session Won't Import Python Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543783/tmux-session-wont-import-python-module?rq=1). If you start the tmux session first and then import tensorflow it should work. At least my issue was resolved when I used this sequence other wise I got an error saying tensorflow module was not found.